# How to avoid user from entering empty string in ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery ajax post and when a user wirte and press enter in a messagebox this ajax triggers. but when the user writes Nothing and press enter this ajax is triggered and return something. but how can I catch the empty strings from user?

```
cliKeyPressed : function(e) {

        if(typeof e === "undefined" ) e = window.event;
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
          var previousLine = "";
          if($('#terminal').text()!== ""){
            previousLine = $('#terminal').text();
            previousLine = previousLine.replace("you entered: ", " ");
          }
          var inputData = $(e.currentTarget).val();

          $('#terminal').text(previousLine + "\r\n" + inputData + "\r\n");
                    AjaxPost(inputData);

        }

AjaxPost : function(data) {

      $.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       url : "/api/user",
       datatype : "application/json",
       contentType: " text/plain",
       data : dataAttribute,
       success : function(data) {

       },
       error : function(error) {

       },
```

Comment: Can you maybe set up a working jsfiddle so we can see what is going on? It seems to me that Krasimir answers your question. If that is not the case you need to be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

You are already doing it. Just move the calling of the AjaxPost inside the *if* statement:

```
if(typeof e === "undefined" ) e = window.event;
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        var previousLine = "";
        if($('#terminal').text() !== "" && $(e.currentTarget).val() !== ""){
            previousLine = $('#terminal').text();
            previousLine = previousLine.replace("you entered: ", " ");
            var inputData = $(e.currentTarget).val();
            $('#terminal').text(previousLine + "\r\n" + inputData + "\r\n");
            AjaxPost(inputData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, create a jsfiddler and we can take a look.

Comment: I do not know how to create it because of this ajax server side

Comment: Ah, I know saw that you send inputData to the AjaxPost. Then you should add one more condition into your if statement. I just updated my answer. Check it out.